# Create Seq[T] reflectively for a T known runtime

Tags: scala, types, reflection

I have a type `T` known reflectively runtime as a value of `scala.reflect.runtime.Type`. I would like to create a type value representing `scala.collection.Seq[T]`. How can I do this?

A background what I want this for:

I want to be able to extract reflectively generic types contained in companion objects of various types. The types have a form of `type As[T] = T` or `type As[T] = Seq[T]`. I want to be able to get a concrete type in a form of `X` or `Seq[X]` for any `X`. The first case is already working for me, as in that case I simply return a `Type` of `X` I already have. The second case is harder - I have a `Type` for `Seq[T]` which is generic and a `Type` for a concrete `X`, but I do not know how could I either modify the `Seq[T]` I already have or create a brand new `Seq[X]`.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Wrap {
  type As[T] = T
}
case class Wrap[T](value: T)

object WrapSeq {
  type As[T] = Seq[T]
}
case class WrapSeq[T](value: Seq[T])

object Main extends App {

  def checkType(typeSignature: Type): Type = {
    // find mapping in the companion object
    val companion = typeSignature.typeSymbol.companion
    val member = companion.typeSignature.member(TypeName("As"))

    if (member != NoSymbol && member.isType) {
      val memberType = member.asType

      def extractSingleType(types: Seq[Type]): Option[Type] = types match {
        case Seq(head) => Some(head)
        case _ => None
      }
      (memberType.typeParams, typeSignature.typeArgs) match {
        case (Seq(typePar), Seq(typeArg)) if memberType.isAliasType =>
          if (member.typeSignature.resultType.typeSymbol.fullName == typePar.fullName) {
            // As[T] == T
            typeArg
          } else if (member.typeSignature.resultType.typeSymbol.fullName == "scala.collection.Seq" && extractSingleType(member.typeSignature.resultType.typeArgs).exists(_.typeSymbol.name == typePar.name)) {
            // As[T] == Seq[T]
            // we want to return Seq[typeArg] here
            // we need to construct the type reflectively somehow
            ???
          } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Unsupported As value $typePar for $typeSignature")
          }
        case _ => // no type parameter, handle the plain type
          member.typeSignature
      }
    } else {
      typeSignature
    }
  }

  println(checkType(typeOf[Wrap[String]])) // output: String

  println(checkType(typeOf[WrapSeq[String]])) // desired output: Seq[String]

}
```

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve?

Comment: I am creating a JSON schema for classes I serialize. The `As` type alias is used to describe a serialization enoder result (encoders are Borer or Circe).

Comment: If you know the type of the classes you try to serialize you might as well use compile time reflection. This way you won't have issues with type erasure

Comment: Yes, that is another solution (which has its own complications). Before I try it that way, I am checking if reflection can get me what I need. The type erasure is already handled by the code above (I have the concrete types I need). It is "only" constructing the `Seq[X]` which I miss to have this fully working.

Comment: You could store runtime type of `X` inside wrappers companion if you are considering hacky solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It shows the answer is actually very easy, once you know what to look for. Using [appliedType](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.html#appliedType(tycon:Types.this.Type,args:List%5BTypes.this.Type%5D):Types.this.Type) does exactly what I need:

```
appliedType(typeOf[Seq[_]], typeArg)
```

Using `appliedType` can even make the `checkType` function shorted and more flexible: it can now handle any generic type, not only `Seq`:

```
  def checkType(typeSignature: Type): Type = {
    // find mapping in the companion object
    val companion = typeSignature.typeSymbol.companion
    val member = companion.typeSignature.member(TypeName("As"))

    if (member != NoSymbol && member.isType) {
      if (member.asType.typeParams.size == typeSignature.typeArgs.size) {
        appliedType(member.typeSignature, typeSignature.typeArgs)
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(s"Type parameters not matching in JsonType value ${member.typeSignature} for $typeSignature")
      }
    } else {
      typeSignature
    }
  }
```